# Recover data from GPT NTFS partition after deletion

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, gpt

I accidentally deleted a NTFS partition of 1600 GiB in a 2 TB hard disk. The partition had 355 GiB of data. I tried to recover it using several utilities but could not.

I know that the partition starts in sector 551585791. So to recover the partition, I want to manually specify the partition's location in the GPT partition table. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, what is manually? Without using a utility?

Comment: by utility you mean diskpart? knowing the utility will assist in a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard tool for manipulating GPTs is [gdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/).

(Edit for the updated question) Use gdisk's "create a new partition" command. When it asks you for "First sector", input "551585791".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried parted? (CLI) or gparted (graphical) -- http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

Comment: Do try the gparted live CD. You can specify the partition size yourself. Since your deleted partition did not have any data, you can create new GPT partitions with as much sizes as you want.

Comment: So it had data before you deleted it? Are you trying to recover the data?

Comment: see this link -- http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1632902 before you do anything with this drive, make an exact copy of this drive on another drive 2TB disk. The link has that detail as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using parted:

```
parted $DEVICE
GNU Parted 3.1
Using $DEVICE
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) mktable
New disk label type? gpt
(parted)
```

After this, you can create new partitions and the like using the various commands available; type “help” for more information; but for parted, this is the `newpart` command.  It will prompt you for all of the information that it needs, just like the `mktable` command does.

Also, note that the creation of a GPT will also create a so-called “protective” MBR; see [Wikipedia’s article on the GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) for more information.